# Lottery number analysis

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to perform some basic analysis on Lotto results :)

I have a database that looks something like:

```
id|no|day|dd|mmm|yyyy|n1|n2|n3|n4|n5|n6|bb|jackpot|wins|machine|set
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1 |22|mon|22|aug|1999|01|05|11|29|38|39|04|2003202| 1  | Topaz | 3
2 |23|tue|24|aug|1999|01|06|16|21|25|39|03|2003202| 2  | Pearl | 1
```

That's just an example. So, n1 to n6 are standard balls in the lottery and bb stands for the bonus ball.

I want to write a PHP/SQL code that will display just one random sequence of numbers that have yet to come out. However, If the numbers 01, 04, 05, 11, 29, 38 and 39 have come out, I don't want the code to print out them numbers but just in a different order, as in theory them set of numbers are already winning numbers.

I just can't get my head around the logic of this. I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_shuffle.asp ?

Comment: "I want to write a PHP/SQL code that will display a sequence of numbers that have yet to come out."... I'm not sure what this means. You do realize that there are millions of permutations in a typical lotto draw. Do you want to output every permutation not in your database?

Comment: No, it'll just generate one random sequence, sorry for not stating that

Comment: So you want to generate a set of seven numbers and check for the presence of said sequence in your dataset? First suggestion: make sure that you're storing the values in ascending order. This will simplify your problem greatly.

Comment: From the example you've given it looks like the balls are in ascending order (with the exception of the bonus which is separate anyway). Is this always the case in your database?

Comment: Yeah the balls are stored asc order except for bonus ball - this can be changed easily if this is not the best way

Comment: Get all of the permutations for your number set (ex: `010512034523`, `011203230545`, etc.), do a query first to see if there are entries in that list (I'd have a combined number field too), and if not, get a new list, if so, iterate until you find the first without a match.

Comment: @JaredFarrish but that doesn't take into account different number orders. e.g., with that method, 010512034523 is different from 050112034523 (reversed first 2 numbers). When in fact, both these strings are to be considered equal.

Comment: @HappyTimeGopher - Hmm. It could be I am thinking of it backwards (is the purpose *to get a literal set of numbers in which **none** of those have come out*?). So then really, it's querying for permutations and rejecting and *not* reordering. So it would have to skip the last part. Somehow, I think a D table makes sense here.

Comment: This is an interesting problem. I think I can write 1 query that will output an unlimited number of unique results. We'll see...

Comment: @HappyTimeGopher - The question lies in how *unique* is defined. Unique sequence parts, unique orientation of sequence, or unique individual numbers (sequence-agnostic)? The latter, the best way I can think of is to find each number NOT found in any of the number fields, and seed the random array with these numbers. The other two seem to require seek or relationship of permutation.

Comment: Another consideration: Can the same number appear twice? Does the lottery only have 1 of each ball numbered 1-49?

Comment: @HappyTimeGopher - God I hope so. That'd be a lot of damn balls. `:P`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the balls are stored in ascending order in your database like the examples you've given, you could just generate a random sequence of 6 numbers, sort them and then generate 1 random bonus number. Once you've done that it would just be a matter of doing a simple SQL query into your database and seeing if it comes back with a result:

```
$nums=...//generate your 6 numbers plus bonus number here
sort($nums);

$mysqli=new mysqli('...','...','...','...');
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table
    WHERE n1=? AND n2=? AND n3=? AND n4=? AND n5=? AND n6=? AND bb=?");
$stmt->bind_param('iiiiiii', $nums[0], $nums[1], $nums[2], $nums[3], $nums[4], $nums[5], $nums[6]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

if($stmt->num_rows==0)
    //your numbers have not been drawn before - return them
else
    //otherwise loop round and try again
```

As long as both list of numbers (but not the bonus ball) are sorted you won't have any problems with a different ordering of an already drawn set of numbers.

This will become less efficient as your database of previous draws gets fuller, but I don't think you'll have to worry about that for a few decades. :-)

Comment: The balls can be in any order. 123 should be considered the same as 312.

Comment: @HappyTimeGopher Hence the sorting of the randomly generated balls.

Comment: You're right - I missed that. As a performance improvement (suggested by @JaredFarrish), an additional column could be created with all the numbers run together. Then throw an index on it and even in a few decades it will fly.

Comment: @HappyTimeGopher I like the index idea - but the inefficiency I was talking about was generating a sequence which has not been seen before. Right now that's easy - there's been something 18000 draws (rough estimation), so there are a large number of the 13.7 million different combinations still left undrawn. Fast-forward a few decades (centuries?) and the number of undrawn combinations will be much smaller so generating one of them at random will become a lot harder.

Comment: I don't quite understand what this is; is this part of a seek algorithm, rejecting and recalculating in a loop until no result is found? Second, are the `n1=?` question marks meant to denote a placeholder, a la PDO?

Comment: @JaredFarrish I added a bit of PHP to elaborate on what I meant. It was part of a prepared statement.

Comment: Here's a way to smooth out the inefficiencies with seeking. Generate a unique, order independent hash of each sequence of numbers. For example: $hash = ( $n1+$n2+$n3+$n4+$n5+$n6+$bb ) . ( $n1*$n2*$n3*$n4*$n5*$n6*$bb ); Generate this en masse and store in it's own column. Good idea?

Comment: @HappyTimeGopher - I don't see what the improvement is per se. Searching for a fixed number value versus hashing per seek interation request, I don't see the benefit, but I see the cost.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look to try and implement something like this using your method.

Answer (score 1):

What about sorting each already drawn result (each row) in some order, ascending maybe, then sort the set of already drawn results (all rows)? Then you will have a easy to look up in list in which you can see what is left to be drawn.

Say for example you want a never drawn set before? You would just have to loop through the list until you spot a "hole", which would be a never before drawn set. If you would like to optimise further you could store at what index you last found a "hole" as well. Then you would never need to loop through the same part of the list twice, and you could even abandon "completed" parts of the list to save disk space, or if you would like the new number you come up with to seam random you could start at a random offset in the list.

To do this effectively you should make an extra column to store the pre-sorted set. For example if you have (5, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2) that column could contain 010203040506. Add in enough zeros so that the numbers occur on a fixed offset basis.